# paypal in Angular 16

Tags: node.js, angular, paypal, paypal-sandbox

`hi, i'm trying to use paypal buttons in angular. I have a server side in node js and a "paypal component". Here is my code in angular

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { loadScript, PayPalNamespace } from "@paypal/paypal-js";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
selector: 'app-paypal-payment',
templateUrl: './paypal.component.html',
styleUrls: \['./paypal.component.css'\],
})
export class PaypalPaymentComponent implements OnInit {

PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID: string = 'your_client_id';

@ViewChild('paypalRef', { static: true }) private paypalRef!: ElementRef;

constructor(private router: Router) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
this.renderPaypalButton();
}

renderPaypalButton() {
let orderRef: string | null = null;

loadScript({ "client-id": this.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID, currency: 'SGD' })
  .then((loadedPaypal) => {
    if (loadedPaypal) {
      const paypal: PayPalNamespace = loadedPaypal;
      paypal.Buttons({
        style: {
          layout: 'vertical',
          color: 'blue',
          shape: 'rect',
          label: 'paypal',
        },
        createOrder: (data, actions) => {
          const postData = {
            // Remplacez avec les détails de votre commande
          };
          return fetch("http://localhost:3000/paypal/orders", {
            method: "post",
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(postData)
          })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((response) => {
              orderRef = response.orderRef;
              return response.id;
            });
        },
        onApprove: (data, actions) => {
          return fetch(`http://localhost:3000/paypal/orders/${data.orderID}/capture`, {
            method: "post",
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
          })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((orderData) => {
              const errorDetail = Array.isArray(orderData.details) && orderData.details[0];

              if (errorDetail && errorDetail.issue === 'INSTRUMENT_DECLINED') {
                return actions.restart();
              }
              const transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];

              this.paypalRedirect(transaction.status, orderRef);
            });
        },
        onCancel: () => {
          // Gérer l'annulation du paiement
        },
        onError: (err) => {
          this.paypalRedirect('ERROR', orderRef);
        }
      }).render(this.paypalRef.nativeElement);
    } else {
      console.error("Le script PayPal n'a pas été chargé correctement.");
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Échec du chargement du script SDK PayPal JS", error);
  });

}

paypalRedirect(status: string, orderRef: string | null) {
switch (status) {
case 'COMPLETED':
if (orderRef) {
this.router.navigate(\['/result/success/' + orderRef\]);
} else {
console.error("Référence de commande manquante pour la redirection vers le succès.");
}
break;
case 'ERROR':
if (orderRef) {
this.router.navigate(\['/result/error/' + orderRef\]);
} else {
console.error("Référence de commande manquante pour la redirection vers l'erreur.");
}
break;
default:
console.error("Statut inconnu pour la redirection.");
break;
}
}
}
```

in HTML, i just have this : <div #paypalRef  ></div>

I have two big errors in angular : Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2722)
const paypal: PayPalNamespace for paypal.Buttons  and Object literal may only specify known properties, and '"client-id"' does not exist in type 'PayPalScriptOptions'.ts(2353)
(property) "client-id": string for "client-id" in loadScript.

```
for information, here is my server.js in node.js : const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const async = require('async');
const httpHelper = require('./httpHelper');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Configurez les identifiants PayPal
const PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID = '';
const PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET = '';

// Route pour obtenir un jeton d'accès PayPal
app.post('/getAccessToken', (req, res) =\> {
generateAccessToken((err, result) =\> {
if (err) {
console.error(err);
res.status(500).json({ message: 'Erreur lors de la récupération du jeton d'accès PayPal' });
} else {
res.json(result);
}
});
});

// Route pour créer une commande PayPal
app.post('/createPaypalOrder', (req, res) =\> {
const accessToken = req.body.access_token; // 
const totalPrice = totalPanier(); // Obtenez le prix total à partir du panier

createPaypalOrder(req, res, (err, result) =\> {
if (err) {
console.error(err);
res.status(500).json({ message: 'Erreur lors de la création de la commande PayPal' });
} else {
res.json(result);
}
});
});

function generateAccessToken(cb) {

async.waterfall(
    [
        (callback) => {
            var url =  "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token";
            var method = "POST";
            var headers = {
                Authorization:
            "Basic " + Buffer.from(CONFIG.PAYPAL.clientId + ":"              
            } 
            var postData = "grant_type=client_credentials";

            httpHelper.makeRequest(url, method, postData, headers, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    logger.error('Error : %o', JSON.stringify(err));
                    callback(err, null);
                } else {
                    logger.debug('Success : %o ', JSON.stringify(result));
                    callback(null, result);
                }

            });
        }

    ],
    (err, result) => {
        cb(err, result)
    }
);

}

function createPaypalOrder(accessToken, totalPrice, cb) {
// Préparez la requête pour créer une commande PayPal avec le prix dynamique
const url = `https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders`;
const method = "POST";
const headers = {
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"Authorization": `Bearer ${accessToken}`
};

const postData = {
  intent: "CAPTURE",
  purchase_units: [
    {
      amount: {
        currency_code: 'USD', // Devise
        value: totalPrice.toFixed(2), // Prix du panier
      },
    },
  ],
  application_context: {
    shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING'
  }
};

const requestBody = JSON.stringify(postData);

httpHelper.makeRequest(url, method, requestBody, headers, (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Erreur : ', JSON.stringify(err));
  } else {
    console.debug('Success : ', JSON.stringify(result));
  }
  
  cb(err, result);
});

}

// Démarrez le serveur
const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () =\> {
console.log(`Serveur Node.js écoutant sur le port ${port}`);
});

and here the httpHelper :

const fetch = require('node-fetch');

function makeRequest(url, method, body, headers, callback) {

if(method == 'GET') {
    var options = {
        method: method,
        headers: headers
    }
} else {
    var options = {
        method: method,
        body:    body,
        headers: headers
    }
}
 
fetch(url, options)
.then(res => res.json())
.then( data => {
    callback(null, data);
  },
  err => {
    callback(err, null);
  });

}

module.exports = {
makeRequest: makeRequest
}
```

I tried to remove undified error in angular bit i can't. I had install librarie (npm install paypal-rest-sdk and npm install @paypal/paypal-js. i just don't understand why these two errors persists`

Comment: its a long shot but try to change loadScript({ "client-id" to loadScript({ "clientId" . Add console.log at loadedPaypal to see what u r getting from paypal